# Вопрос о MVC на конкретном примере

Tags: mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Пишу приложение с использованием составного шаблона MVC.
**Model** включает в себя посредством композиции класс **User**.
Есть необходимость во **View** при нажатии на элемент JTree (объект) в таблице рядом выводить данные связанные с этой категорией (множество). 
Можно ли в этом случае прямо с **View** обращаться к объекту **User** для отображения данных или нужно все делать исключительно через контроллер и модель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В исходном варианте паттерна MVC, где внешние сигналы принимает представление допускается обращение к модели из представления, в варианте Model 2, который повсеместно используется для Web и где внешние сигналы принимает контроллер, обращение к модели из представления считаются грубым нарушением паттерна.